# Getting 502 Bad Gateway error and sending a email with django, nginx, gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm trying to send a email using the django send_mail function gmail SMTP on my web server and and I got the 502 Bad Gateway error.

I'm using nginx and gunicorn.

Here is my error.log:

```
2014/04/12 16:46:55 [error] 26846#0: *11 upstream prematurely closed connection while                
reading response header from upstream, client: 179.162.163.62, server: example.com, 
request: "POST /contact/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/contact/", host: 
"example.com", referrer: "http://example.com/contact/"
```

Ngnix file:

```
upstream example_gunicorn {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name .example.com;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    location /static/ {
        alias /deploy/sites/example/static/; # STATIC_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location /media/ {
        alias /deploy/sites/example/media/; # MEDIA_ROOT
        expires 30d;
    }

    location / {
        # checks for static file, if not found proxy to app
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass   http://example_gunicorn;
    }
}
```

Comment: check the django error log

Answer (score 4):

502 doesn't say much about what the actual error is... I'll draw you a picture:

```
Client/Browser              Server                   Web Server               
    |         request         |                           |
    |------------------------>|                           |
    |                         |  attempt to send mail     |
    |                         |-------------------------> |
    |                         |                         ERROR 
    |                         |       error message       |          
    |                         |<--------------------------|
    |       502               |                           |
    |<----------------------- |                           |
```

The arrows represent communication. Time increases as you move down the image.

So the webserver hides the actual error from the end user, this is pretty sensable behavior in a production environment. You need to look in the web server logs.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using a CentOS7 droplet on DigitalOcean. I am using Django 1.6.5 and gunicorn.

I solved it by explicitly specifying `EMAIL_HOST = "74.125.22.108"` instead of `EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"` in `settings.py`. In my case, it was an IPv6 issue, as DigitalOcean [does not allow](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/outgoing-connections-on-port-25-587-143-blocked-over-ipv6) SMTP over IPv6.

NOTE: For security purposes, always verify the IPv4 address of smtp.gmail.com (using `dig` or similar) before blindly pasting it into code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost example.com
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

Also could be usefull to increase your `proxy_read_timeout 60s;` in server config. By default it's 60s, but you could make it 360s or something.
And don't forget to restart services (networking, nginx, postfix, etc)